# Cannot find files from output to write.csv in R

Tags: r

I am running into some trouble with the following code.

```
dataframe_temp = data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), 
                            City = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), 
                            Qty = c(20, 14, 40, 50, 60))

dataframe.list <- list()

for (city in unique(dataframe_temp$City)) { 

  print(city)

  dataframe.list[[i]] = subset(dataframe_temp, City == city) 


  write.csv(x = dataframe.list[[i]], file = paste0("C:\\Users\\my.name\\Desktop", "dataframe_for_city_", city,".csv")) 
}
```

Everything seems to run fine but I can't find the files on my desktop!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> Everything seems to run fine but I can't find the files on my desktop!

Because they’re not on your desktop, they are in the *parent folder* (`C:\Users\my.name`), in files named `Desktopdataframe_for_city_‹city›.csv`.

You forgot the backslash between `Desktop` and the filename. You can also use `file.path` to construct paths with less chance for such errors than with `paste0`.

Comment: Hi, I changed it to this C:\\Users\\my.name\\Desktop\\. But I still cannot see the files. I don't think I understand your solution, sorry. Thank you. I even looked in C:\Users\my.name and could not see anything!